# Unable to use any_instance on Twitter gem's user_timline

Tags: ruby, twitter, mocking, stub

I am still quite fresh to Ruby, and especially testing in Ruby. Hopefully the code is not a trainwreck :) I am having issues using any_instance with the Twitter gem, while it works fine on my own classes.

This is (what I believe) the relevant code

```
require 'twitter'

require 'minitest/unit'
require 'mocha/mini_test'

omitting for brevity....

 args = { id: 573536452149182464, id_str: 73536452149182464, text: 'This is an initial tweet from the user'}
 initial_tweet = ::Twitter::Tweet.new(args)
 ::Twitter::REST::Timelines.any_instance.stubs(:user_timeline).returns(initial_tweet)
```

The code produces the following error:

```
 Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `any_instance|' for Twitter::REST::Timelines:Module
```

Are principles to stubbing gems different, am I approaching it wrong?

EDIT: I have added the entire code for the two classes below.

**twitter.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cinch'
require 'cinch/commands'
require 'twitter'
require 'shorturl'

module Gigabot
 module Commands
   class Twitter
     include Cinch::Plugin
     include Cinch::Commands

      def initialize(bot)
       super(bot)
       @client = create_client
       @follow = config[:follow]
       @channels = bot.config.channels
       @latest_tweets = Hash.new
       set_initial_tweets
      end

     timer 60, method: :twitter_update
     def twitter_update
         @follow.each do |user|
            new_tweet = @client.user_timeline(user, options = {exclude_replies: true}).first
            if @latest_tweets[user] != new_tweet
            short_url = ShortURL.shorten("https://twitter.com/#{user}/status/#{new_tweet.id}")
            reply = Format(:bold, "<#{user}> ") + "#{new_tweet.full_text} [#{short_url}]"
            reply = reply.gsub(/\n/,' ')

            @channels.each {|channel| Channel(channel).send(reply)}
            @latest_tweets[user] = new_tweet
          end
        end
      end


      private
      def create_client
        ::Twitter::REST::Client.new do |c|
          c.consumer_key        = config[:consumer_key]
          c.consumer_secret     = config[:consumer_secret]
          c.access_token        = config[:access_token]
          c.access_token_secret = config[:access_token_secret]
        end
     end

      def set_initial_tweets
         @follow.each do |user|
           @latest_tweets[user] = @client.user_timeline(user, options = {exclude_replies: true}).first
        end
     end
   end
 end
```

end

**twitter_test.rb**

```
require 'twitter'

require 'minitest/unit'
require 'mocha/mini_test'


require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../helper'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../../../lib/gigabot/commands/twitter'

module Gigabot
  module Commands
    class TwitterTest < TestCase

       def setup
        bot = Cinch::Bot.new
        bot.loggers.level = :fatal

        bot.config.plugins.options[Twitter] = {
            consumer_key: 'test_key',
            consumer_secret: 'test_key_secret',
            access_token: 'test_access_token',
            access_token_secret: 'test_access_token_secret',
            follow: %w(follow1 follow2)
        }

        args = { id: 573536452149182464, id_str: 73536452149182464, text: 'This is an initial tweet from the user'}
        initial_tweet = ::Twitter::Tweet.new(args)
        ::Twitter::REST::Timelines.any_instance.stubs(:user_timeline).returns(initial_tweet)
        @plugin = Twitter.new(bot)
       end

       def test_create_twitter_client_on_initialize
         refute_nil(@plugin.instance_variable_get(:@client))
       end

     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: What are you trying to test? You probably shouldn't omit something. Your test declares what are are trying to do.

Comment: Fair point, I just thought it would be messy for you people helping. I am trying to see if the client has been created, the class creates the client then calls the get user timeline in the init method. I have added the two entire classes

Comment: You are pretty far off base which is why you aren't getting a lot of responses. Read this: http://substantial.com/blog/2015/1/22/mocks-stubs-and-spies-oh-mys and I meant omitting your test. You don't have anything in your test...

Comment: I understand that I am not using the "describe, it" syntax. I have already written 6 other test classes that work fine. Although if that is not the proper way to do it I will take a look at doing it the way the blog posts talks about. Thanks I will give it a go, and probably just read a bit more up on the subject

Comment: It's easier to learn it right then to try to break bad habits. Use the test suite as it was designed to be used and you will save yourself time, headache and so much more.